# Should I still use TCPClient to write servers or has something better emerged?

Tags: c#, winforms, xna, tcpclient

Years ago when writing a server for a simple pong game I was making I used a TCPClient and referenced some .NET Framework 101 code sample page that included an example of a server and client program written using either the .NET Framework 1.1 or 2.0.

I need to write another server and I was wondering if there is anything better to use now. I remember the code being pretty low-level with a lot of try-catches and boiler-plate code.

Has the .NET Framework 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, or 4.0 had any advancements in the implementation of a simple client-server program? What about any simple user-created wrappers?

By the way, I am not necessarily against using the TCPClient class. I just am wondering if anything else has come along to further abstract the class and/or facilitate in the creation of a server program.

Comment: Try WCF. It's the wheel you shouldn't reinvent.

Comment: @John: Do you have any code examples? I'm not using ASP and Google didn't return much about C# and WCF.

Comment: Totally agree - searching for "C# nd WCF" on bing 3+ millons, on google - 11+ millions. :)

Comment: It could return 100 million results for all I care.. None of the results seemed too relevant to my question.

Comment: why the tag xna and winforms? if you need suggestions on how to implement a server, WCF or not, start telling what your server should do, what kind of end point you plan to expose and so on... depending on how/what you want to expose, an IIS hosted wcf service could help, or something completely different instead. What do you need to serve?

Answer (score 0):

WCF is a great choice.  It gives you a lot of flexibility and power.  Here's a simple guide for getting started:  [MSDN Documentation - Getting Started with WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms734712%28VS.100%29.aspx).  This [blog post from Switch on the Code](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication) is even more straightforward.

Another option is the using C# bindings to the open source project [0MQ](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3aclr).  It abstracts away the complexity of sockets without too much overhead and gives you a lot of power.  From the section 0MQ in 100 words:

*ØMQ (ZeroMQ, 0MQ, zmq) looks like an embeddable networking library but acts like a concurrency framework. It gives you sockets that carry whole messages across various transports like in-process, inter-process, TCP, and multicast. You can connect sockets N-to-N with patterns like fanout, pub-sub, task distribution, and request-reply. It's fast enough to be the fabric for clustered products. Its asynchronous I/O model gives you scalable multicore applications, built as asynchronous message-processing tasks. It has a score of language APIs and runs on most operating systems. ØMQ is from iMatix and is LGPL open source*